# Custom field with unconventional character in key for scrappy.Item

Tags: python, scrapy

Let's say I want to define a item model called Product that has a key named `@type`.

```
class Product(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    stock = scrapy.Field()
    @type = scrapy.Field()
```

Obviously the following definition will be illegal in python due to the fact that `@type` is not a valid instance variable name.

Still it is valid to have JSON like this:

```
{
  name: "Battery",
  price: 1.00,
  stock: 10,
  @type: "Product"
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this properly in Scrapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`scrapy.Item`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#scrapy.item.Item) is based on a `dict` and stores fields in [`fields`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#scrapy.item.Item.fields), override `__init__()`:

```
class Product(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    stock = scrapy.Field()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['@type'] = Field()
```

---

Example spider:

```
from scrapy import Item, Field
from scrapy import Spider


class Product(Item):
    name = Field()
    price = Field()
    stock = Field()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['@type'] = Field()


class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "product_spider"  
    start_urls = ['http://google.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = Product()
        item['name'] = 'Test name'
        item['price'] = 0
        item['stock'] = True
        item['@type'] = 'Test type'
        return item
```

Produces:

```
$ scrapy runspider spider1.py
2014-08-11 14:32:00-0400 [product_spider] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.google.com/>
{'@type': 'Test type', 'name': 'Test name', 'price': 0, 'stock': True}
```